Custom components with Direct2D paint
I have a project with alot of painted controls, such as grids, coloring, shapes, images, and so on. I decided to try using GPU acceleration to make the entire solution smoother and faster so that a gradual migration from normal GDI (TCanvas) to GPU-accelerated (TDirect2DCanas) will be undertaken for those components that can really benefit from it.
I started to research and to make initial tests, because I don't even know if TDirect2DCanvas is what I exactly need. But I found this post by François (ICS owner) that is basically the same as the Embarcadero document here.
These documents helped me understand the basics. To do a test, I built a component just like in the François post, which is a custom panel with overridden paint events and canvas, just like the other document.
I also made some changes to have a close as possible copy of a TPanel (copy-paste from TCustomPanel class and adapted to use TDirect2DCanvas), just with hardware acceleration as a plus. The code is:
unit CustomPanel;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Messages,
    Winapi.D2D1,
    Winapi.Windows,
    System.Classes,
    System.SysUtils,
    Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.ExtCtrls,
    Vcl.Direct2D,
    Vcl.Controls,
    Vcl.Themes;

type
    CustomD2DPanel = class(TPanel)
    private
        FD2DCanvas             : TDirect2DCanvas;
        FPrevRenderTarget      : IntPtr;
        FOnPaint               : TNotifyEvent;
        FOnCreateRenderTarget  : TNotifyEvent;
        function  CreateD2DCanvas: Boolean;
        procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
        procedure WMPaint(var Msg: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
        procedure WMSize(var Msg: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
        // Bevels?
        procedure D2DFrame3D(ACanvas: TDirect2DCanvas; var Rect: TRect; TopColor, BottomColor: TColor; Width: Integer);
    protected
        procedure CreateWnd; override;
        function  GetRenderTarget : ID2D1HwndRenderTarget;
        procedure TriggerCreateRenderTarget; virtual;
    public
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Paint; override;
        property D2DCanvas             : TDirect2DCanvas
                                                   read  FD2DCanvas;
        property RenderTarget          : ID2D1HwndRenderTarget
                                                   read  GetRenderTarget;
        property OnPaint               : TNotifyEvent
                                                   read  FOnPaint
                                                   write FOnPaint;
        property OnCreateRenderTarget  : TNotifyEvent
                                                   read  FOnCreateRenderTarget
                                                   write FOnCreateRenderTarget;
    end;

    D2DPanel = class(CustomD2DPanel)
    published
        property Align;
        property Anchors;
        property Canvas;
        property Color;
        property D2DCanvas;
        property RenderTarget;
        property BevelEdges;
        property BevelInner;
        property BevelOuter;
        property BevelKind;
        property BevelWidth;
        property BorderWidth;
        property Ctl3D;
        property ParentBackground;
        property ParentCtl3D;
        property OnAlignInsertBefore;
        property OnAlignPosition;
        property OnDockDrop;
        property OnDockOver;
        property OnEnter;
        property OnExit;
        property OnGetSiteInfo;
        property OnKeyDown;
        property OnKeyPress;
        property OnKeyUp;
        property OnUnDock;
        property DragCursor;
        property DragMode;
        property ParentBiDiMode;
        property ParentColor;
        property ParentFont;
        property ParentShowHint;
        property PopupMenu;
        property OnCanResize;
        property OnClick;
        property OnConstrainedResize;
        property OnContextPopup;
        property OnDblClick;
        property OnDragDrop;
        property OnDragOver;
        property OnEndDock;
        property OnEndDrag;
        property OnMouseActivate;
        property OnMouseDown;
        property OnMouseEnter;
        property OnMouseLeave;
        property OnMouseMove;
        property OnMouseUp;
        property OnMouseWheel;
        property OnMouseWheelDown;
        property OnMouseWheelUp;
        property OnResize;
        property OnStartDock;
        property OnStartDrag;
        property OnPaint;
    end;

implementation

{ CustomD2DPanel }

destructor CustomD2DPanel.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(FD2DCanvas);
    inherited Destroy;
end;

function CustomD2DPanel.CreateD2DCanvas: Boolean;
begin
    try
        FD2DCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Handle);
        Result     := TRUE;
    except
        Result     := FALSE;
    end;
    TriggerCreateRenderTarget;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.CreateWnd;
begin
    inherited;
    if (Win32MajorVersion < 6) or (Win32Platform <> VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) then
        raise Exception.Create('Your Windows version do not support Direct2D');
    if not CreateD2DCanvas then
        raise Exception.Create('Unable to create Direct2D canvas');
end;

function CustomD2DPanel.GetRenderTarget: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget;
begin
    if FD2DCanvas <> nil then begin
        Result := FD2DCanvas.RenderTarget as ID2D1HwndRenderTarget;
        if FPrevRenderTarget <> IntPtr(Result) then begin
            FPrevRenderTarget := IntPtr(Result);
            TriggerCreateRenderTarget;
        end;
    end
    else
        Result := nil;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.TriggerCreateRenderTarget;
begin
    if Assigned(FOnCreateRenderTarget) then
        FOnCreateRenderTarget(Self);
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.Paint;
const
  Alignments: array[TAlignment] of Longint = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
  VerticalAlignments: array[TVerticalAlignment] of Longint = (DT_TOP, DT_BOTTOM, DT_VCENTER);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  LColor: TColor;
  LStyle: TCustomStyleServices;
  LDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
  TopColor, BottomColor: TColor;
  BaseColor, BaseTopColor, BaseBottomColor: TColor;
  Flags: Longint;

  procedure AdjustColors(Bevel: TPanelBevel);
  begin
    TopColor := BaseTopColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      TopColor := BaseBottomColor;
    BottomColor := BaseBottomColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      BottomColor := BaseTopColor;
  end;

  function CheckParentBackground(AParent: TWinControl): Boolean;
  begin
    if (AParent <> nil) and (AParent is TCustomPanel) then
    begin
      Result := TCustomPanel(AParent).ParentBackground;
      if Result then
        Result := CheckParentBackground(AParent.Parent);
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  end;

begin
  Rect := GetClientRect;

  BaseColor := Color;
  BaseTopColor := clBtnHighlight;
  BaseBottomColor := clBtnShadow;
  LStyle := StyleServices(Self);
  if LStyle.Enabled and (seClient in StyleElements) then
  begin
    LDetails := LStyle.GetElementDetails(tpPanelBackground);
    if LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecFillColor, LColor) and (LColor <> clNone) then
      BaseColor := LColor;
    LDetails := LStyle.GetElementDetails(tpPanelBevel);
    if LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecEdgeHighLightColor, LColor) and (LColor <> clNone) then
      BaseTopColor := LColor;
    if LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecEdgeShadowColor, LColor) and (LColor <> clNone) then
      BaseBottomColor := LColor;
  end;

  if BevelOuter <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelOuter);
    D2DFrame3D(D2DCanvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
  if not (LStyle.Enabled and (csParentBackground in ControlStyle)) then
    D2DFrame3D(D2DCanvas, Rect, BaseColor, BaseColor, BorderWidth)
  else
    InflateRect(Rect, -Integer(BorderWidth), -Integer(BorderWidth));
  if BevelInner <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelInner);
    D2DFrame3D(D2DCanvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
  with FD2DCanvas do
  begin
    if not LStyle.Enabled or not ParentBackground or not (seClient in StyleElements) or
       (not LStyle.IsSystemStyle and (Parent <> nil) and (Parent is TCustomPanel) and
       TCustomPanel(Parent).DoubleBuffered and not CheckParentBackground(Parent))
    then
    begin
      Brush.Color := BaseColor;
      FillRect(Rect);
    end;

    if ShowCaption and (Caption <> '') then
    begin
      Brush.Style := bsClear;
      Font.Assign(Self.Font);
      Flags := DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_SINGLELINE or
        VerticalAlignments[VerticalAlignment] or Alignments[Alignment];
      Flags := DrawTextBiDiModeFlags(Flags);
      if LStyle.Enabled and (seFont in StyleElements) then
      begin
        LDetails := LStyle.GetElementDetails(tpPanelBackground);
        if not LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecTextColor, LColor) or (LColor = clNone) then
          LColor := Font.Color;
        LStyle.DrawText(Handle, LDetails, Caption, Rect, TTextFormatFlags(Flags), LColor)
      end
      else
        DrawText(Handle, Caption, -1, Rect, Flags);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.WMEraseBkGnd(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    Msg.Result := 1;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.WMPaint(var Msg: TWMPaint);
var
    PaintStruct: TPaintStruct;
begin
    BeginPaint(Handle, PaintStruct);
    try
        FD2DCanvas.BeginDraw;
        try
            Paint;
        finally
            FD2DCanvas.EndDraw;
        end;
    finally
        EndPaint(Handle, PaintStruct);
    end;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.WMSize(var Msg: TWMSize);
var
    Size: D2D1_SIZE_U;
begin
    if FD2DCanvas <> nil then begin
        Size := D2D1SizeU(Width, Height);
        ID2D1HwndRenderTarget(FD2DCanvas.RenderTarget).Resize(Size);
    end;
    inherited;
end;

procedure CustomD2DPanel.D2DFrame3D(ACanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
  var Rect: TRect; TopColor, BottomColor: TColor; Width: Integer);

  procedure DoRect;
  var
    TopRight, BottomLeft: TPoint;
  begin
    with ACanvas, Rect do
    begin
      TopRight.X := Right;
      TopRight.Y := Top;
      BottomLeft.X := Left;
      BottomLeft.Y := Bottom;
      Pen.Color := TopColor;
      PolyLine([BottomLeft, TopLeft, TopRight]);
      Pen.Color := BottomColor;
      Dec(BottomLeft.X);
      PolyLine([TopRight, BottomRight, BottomLeft]);
    end;
  end;

begin
  ACanvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  Dec(Rect.Bottom); Dec(Rect.Right);
  while Width > 0 do
  begin
    Dec(Width);
    DoRect;
    InflateRect(Rect, -1, -1);
  end;
  Inc(Rect.Bottom); Inc(Rect.Right);
end;

end.


Apparently it paints over the GPU as it's supposed to (I haven't made intensive tests), but when I drag the custom panel into the Form at design time I have a black panel, which doesn't change even when changing the Color property, but at run time it respects the theme settings (StyleElements.seClient) and Color property (when seClient style disabled of course).
Why the difference between design time and run time? Also, the caption of the component is not drawn, for some reason.  I just copied all of the code of the TCustomPanel.Paint event.
I cannot see a clearly problem with the code above that can cause these problems. Am I taking the right approach?

Some potential source of inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867049/282848

Also, I might add that IMHO OpenGL is easier to work with than Direct2D. And unless you really need antialiasing and very advanced and smooth graphics, plain old GDI is likely good enough.

Have you perhaps considered of switching from VCL to FireMonkey? FMX already draws all of its controls using GPU acceleration. So unless you application has tons of custom components switching to FMX will be much faster since FMX already has equivalents for most standard VCL components meaning you will have to just recreate your VCL form in FMX. Switching to FMX also opens you a lot of other options like ability to support other platforms and not just Windows.

I strongly recommend you check FMX first before you enter the rabit hole of creating dozens of custom components just to use Direct2D paint as it may not be worth the time.

My experience is that FMX is absolutely full of bugs with new ones introduced in every release. On the other hand, VCL has been robust and reliable and almost free of bugs for 30 years now.

Thanks @AndreasRejbrand, ur linked answer inspired me aswell. I think I on a right way now tbh. Antialising and other stuffs is my goal to "modernize" the entire application and seems that rebuild simple components is not needed.
I also forgot to mention that my application works with charts not Delphi native yet but the planning is to convert, already with GPU acceleration.
FMX is not an option (the project have complex custom components) like rebuild dozens of custom components for better rendering is not an option. Just rebuild some custom components that can improve the UX. Tks.

@AndreasRejbrand with the above code did you know why the custom d2d panel is all black even with another color set? look at design time: https://prnt.sc/vWYAWiha5vV-
At runtime, it changes to its defined color: https://prnt.sc/l5WxiF_RKRN7
A curious fact: f I change the application VCL Style the custom d2d panel inherits its style normal (seClient in StyleElements ofc): https://prnt.sc/jvLs3PcLkrxr
It seems to be a bug but I don't know if its my code or Delpi. The code is closer to the embarcadero example above mentioned...

@snowdev: Sorry, I don't have time to look into that.
